# Swap a form on error, or redirect on success using HTMX

Tags: html, htmx

I have a login form marked up like this:

```
<div id="login_form" hx-ext="response-targets">
    <form action="/login" method="POST" hx-boost="true" hx-target="#login_form" hx-target-400="#login_form" hx-swap="innerHTML">
        ...
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

When there's an error, backend returns the form with outlined errors, with 400 status code (hence `response-targets` extension). On success, backend responds `HX-Location` header of user's profile page, where I expect user to be redirected. Put simply:

1. Form should be re-rendered on error (400 Bad Request)
2. User should be redirected to their profile page on success (200 OK)

What actually happens is that HTMX renders entire user's profile page in `#login_form` instead of redirecting, as if `hx-target` overrides or takes precedence over `HX-Location` header.

Tried this without `response-target` plugin, it works the same. With `response-target` plugin I can't omit `hx-target` because then `hx-target-400` is not recognized or handled.

How can I put it together so forms are re-rendered on errors, or redirected to a page on success?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behavior where `hx-target` is populated with the whole page that I wanted to redirect to happens when both `Location` and `HX-Location` headers are present.

Fix is simple - if backend detects that request is coming from HTMX (by checking if `HX-Request` request header exists), it responds with `HX-Location` redirection, and if not it responds with `Location` header.

Reason why I was sending both headers is because I started with an idea of progressive enhancement. My assumption was that HTMX (v1.9.6) will use `HX-Location` when it finds it, with `Location` left as a fallback for request not coming form HTMX (or with JavaScript disabled).

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[Ilija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338473/ilija)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77252592/6309) is about differentiating between HTMX and non-HTMX requests by checking the `HX-Request` header and then responding with either the `HX-Location` or `Location` header accordingly.

That way, you ensure a seamless user experience whether JavaScript is enabled or not, aligning with the idea of progressive enhancement. While HTMX (v1.9.6) might prioritize `HX-Location` over `Location` (see "original answer") was logical, it requires a bit of backend logic to handle the responses based on the request type.

---

Original answer:

The problem seems to be that the [`hx-target` attribute](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-target/) is taking precedence over the [`HX-Location` header](https://htmx.org/headers/hx-location/). The `hx-target` attribute instructs [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) where to place the response, while `HX-Location` header from the server suggests a redirect.

For testing, try and use a small piece of JavaScript with HTMX to handle the redirection based on the `HX-Location` header, overriding the default behavior of HTMX in this scenario.

Add an `hx-trigger` attribute to your form to specify a custom JavaScript function that will handle the `htmx:afterOnLoad` event, which fires after HTMX processes a response:

```html
<div id="login_form" hx-ext="response-targets">
    <form action="/login" method="POST" hx-boost="true" hx-target="#login_form" hx-target-400="#login_form" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-trigger="handleResponse">
        ...
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Define the `handleResponse` function in your JavaScript code. That function will check for the `HX-Location` header in the HTMX response and perform a redirection if it is present:

```js
function handleResponse(event) {
    // Extract the HX-Location header from the HTMX response
    var hxLocation = event.detail.xhr.getResponseHeader('HX-Location');
    
    // If the HX-Location header is present, perform a redirection
    if (hxLocation) {
        window.location.href = hxLocation;
    }
}
```

If the server responds with a `HX-Location` header, the `handleResponse` function will catch it and redirect the user to the specified URL, overriding the default behavior of HTMX in this scenario.

On the other hand, if the server responds with a 400 status code, the `hx-target-400` attribute will still work as intended, and HTMX will re-render the form with the outlined errors.

Comment: I did not find any issue with [those two elements](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Abigskysoftware%2Fhtmx+hx-trigger+HX-Location&type=issues), so this could be a new issue on its own.

Comment: You think this should be submitted as an issue? Curious to see if anyone except me thinks that it should work as I expect it work. ‍♂️

Comment: @Ilija Yes, if this is not working as expected, it might be a bug. Let's see if your bounty will get other answers.

Comment: Found it, it happens when both `HX-Location` and `Location` headers are sent. Whether this is a bug or not is up for a debate. Thank you for the answer.